# Entity Framework slow after upgrade from EF4 to EF6 (EntityFramework.6.2.0)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-4

I'm upgrading an old MVC web application from EF4 to EF6 (and MVC3 to MVC5) using a guide i found on SO.

Functionally appears OK, but I've noticed performance issues.

Specific requests on the prod env for this application running MVC3/EF4 finish in under half a second.
Same in my Dev system after update take seconds.

For comparison, I've created an new test MVC/EF6 solution on the same dev machine that I am working on the migrated application.  I surfaced the below linq via an MCV action, and have found there is a big performance difference, between the two to applications.

Note: both the old and test application have no overheads in the controller constructor, they both only creating the dbContext, and run the query.

```
var sites = DB.Sites.Take(50).Include("Users").OrderBy(s => s.SiteName).ToList();
```

new test EF6 application: 200ms
old application upgraded: 2 seconds

I have profiled the requests on SQL Server, and I can't see any problem there.

I am considering removing the ADO Entity Framework from the old project and starting by adding again. but this was a model first application, and doing this appears to remove all the partial classes, where the metadata has been defined (resulting in lots of compilation errors).

- Should I remove the ADO Entity Framework from the old project - and
  recreate as a database first application?
- Is there something I have missed - that could be causing the issue?
- how can i find out where the time is being used?

**Edit**

I removed the ADO Entity Framework model(edmx) and rediscovered from the database.  This resulted in a lot of refactoring, due to pluralisation difference between EF4 and EF6.  There were also changes to the Add/Update/Delete entities behaviours.

This hasn't resolve the performance issue.

Answer (score 1):

This ones going to be really hard to debug from afar but I'd start by capturing the query thats being created by ef with sql profiler and seeing if you're missing any indexes on the db. SQLServer is a temperamental beast when it comes to producing query plans and if EF has changed its queries from 4 to 6, and theres a reasonable amount of data in the tables, this is most likely to be causing your issue. You might find it just needs a new index or something along those lines.

Another option thats not specifically tied to your problem, but could have an effect is precompiling the views in the EF context, which should reduce the first query time after startup of the application.

Comment: I said in the question I had already profiled the SQL - I had created a brand new application, on the same box, and did a side by side comparison - which showed the issue was in the upgraded apps entity framework - so pre-compilation would not  resolve the issue.  The issue turned out to be configuration - as suspected - of the entity framework.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

in the upgraded app's web.config I found the connection string had: **Pooling=False;**  I removed this.

Additionally in my test app, I found the connectiton string had: **App=EntityFramework**

The performance immediately improved to that of the test application